# Why do these sql counts not match up

Tags: sql, sql-server

i would expect these counts to match but they are off by a few records. What could cause this?

```
DECLARE @ExpectedCount INT = 0;
DECLARE @UpdatedCount INT = 0;

SELECT @ExpectedCount = COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[Table1] t
JOIN [dbo].[Table2] s ON s.IdColumn = t.IdColumn

UPDATE t
SET t.StadiumId = s.StadiumId
FROM [dbo].[Table1] t
JOIN [dbo].[Table2] s ON s.IdColumn = t.IdColumn    

SELECT @UpdatedCount = @@ROWCOUNT

PRINT @ExpectedCount
PRINT @UpdatedCount
```

Comment: Probably `@UpdatedCount` reports only the rows which were actually changed? I mean, if `StadiumId` was `3` before and `3` after, it does not count as "updated".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT COUNT(*) will show the number of rows in the JOIN of t1 and t2.

@@ROWCOUNT after UPDATE ... t1 JOIN t2 will have *the number of rows updated in t1*.

The numbers are different because they are counting different things. A trivial explanation is a row in `t1` for which there are two rows matching in `t2`: the COUNT(*) is 2, the UPDATE count is 1. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try this `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET StadiumId = s.StadiumId
FROM [dbo].[Table2] s 
WHERE s.IdColumn = [dbo].[Table1].IdColumn
```

Comment: this isn't valid syntax for SQL Server

Comment: @Lamak Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b541a/1) where the above syntax works for SQL Server and I have been using it.

Comment: Sorry?, I don't see where the syntax of your answer is used on that fiddle.

Comment: @Lamak Sorry. My mistake Copy/Pasted and forgot to change the `ON`. Fixed now.

Comment: Removed the downvote, but I don't see how this would give different results than the syntax used by op